# Ordenar tabla según varias columnas

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Tengo una bbdd de la que obtengo los resultados y los muestro así:

```
<?php foreach ($all_categories as $cat): ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $cat['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucfirst($cat['name'])); ?></td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="edit_categorie.php?id=<?php echo (int)$cat['id']; ?>" style="margin-right:5px;" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </a>
                <a onclick="javascript:return confirm('¿Confirmar Eliminación?');" href="delete_categorie.php?id=<?php echo (int)$cat['id']; ?>" style="margin-left:5px;" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Se me ordena en orden alfabético de la columna categoria, pero quiero que se me ordene por la primera columna que es el id.
He visto que en muchos sitios de internet para ordenar una tabla por otras columnas hay una pequeña flecha al lado del título de la columna.
No sé si eso se podrá hacer en php o hay algúna otra forma más fácil.

Comment: Eso no es un tema de php, es un tema de la grilla visual y como la estas usando.. en tu caso estas armando una a mano, asi que vas a tener que programar todo a mano... o buscar un componente que ya lo tenga solucionado...

Comment: puedes buscar en google `datatable js` y te saldra el link a una libreria para hacer esto